# Optimal code for two add_rewrite_rule's

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have two custom rewrite rules; after reading allot of great posts here I found a way to make them work.

The question is this:
**Is there a way to merge this code? I'm not sure that the way I wrote it is optimal:**

In my functions.php I have the code of the 1st rule:

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite_cat'); // Rewrite Category
    add_action('query_vars', 'rewrite_query_vars_cat'); 
    add_filter('template_include', 'rewrite_template_include_cat'); 
    function rewrite_cat(){ 
        add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?catname=$matches[1]&currentpage=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    }
    function rewrite_query_vars_cat($query_vars){    
        $query_vars[] = 'currentpage'; 
        $query_vars[] = 'catname'; 
        return $query_vars; 
        } 
    function rewrite_template_include_cat($template){     
        if (get_query_var('currentpage') || get_query_var('catname')){        
            $template = locate_template(array('category.php'));
        }     
            return $template; 
        }
```

After, this is the code of the 2nd rule:

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite_perf'); // Rewrite Perf
    add_action('query_vars', 'rewrite_query_vars_perf'); 
    add_filter('template_include', 'rewrite_template_include_perf'); 
    function rewrite_perf(){ 
        add_rewrite_rule('cam/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=cam&sgcatname=$matches[1]&perf=$matches[2]', 'top');
    }
    function rewrite_query_vars_perf($query_vars){  
        $query_vars[] = 'sgcatname'; 
        $query_vars[] = 'perf'; 
        return $query_vars; 
        } 
    function rewrite_template_include_perf($template){     
        if (get_query_var('sgcatname') || get_query_var('perf')){        
            $template_perf = locate_template(array('single.php'));
        }     
            return $template; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code:

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite_init'); // Rewrite
    add_action('query_vars', 'rewrite_query_vars'); 
    add_filter('template_include', 'rewrite_template_include'); 
    function rewrite_init(){ 
        add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?catname=$matches[1]&currentpage=$matches[2]', 'top');
        add_rewrite_rule('cam/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=cam&perf=$matches[1]', 'top');
    }
    function rewrite_query_vars($query_vars){    
        $query_vars[] = 'currentpage'; 
        $query_vars[] = 'catname'; 
        $query_vars[] = 'perf'; 
        return $query_vars; 
    } 
    function rewrite_template_include($template){     
        if(get_query_var('currentpage') || get_query_var('catname')){        
            $template = locate_template(array('category.php'));
        } elseif(get_query_var('perf')){
            $template = locate_template(array('single.php'));
        }
            return $template; 
    }
```